# RethinkDB: Get fields inside indexes instead of just index names

Tags: rethinkdb

I am trying to make a tool that will live-copy a DB from one RethinkDB host to another, however I am hung-up on the fact I can't seem to find out what is actually in each index. I have tried

```
r.db('db').table('table').index_list()
```

and

```
r.db('db').table('table').info()
```

I even tried

```
r.db('db').table('table').index_list().info()
```

But all three only returned the names of the indexes and not what fields are in them. This makes it impossible to re-create the table on the destination DB exactly the same as the source.

What am I missing here? There has to be a way to do this, or is this just something missing from RethinkDB? If so, does anyone know why?

Comment: is there a particular reason you wouldn't just use replication and put the RethinkDB instances in a cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual I only get answers from people who don't read my question or who want to answer questions that weren't asked.

The solution is to parse the data from

```
r.db('db').table('table').index_status()
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are computed from the documents in the table.  If you read all of the documents from the first table (with e.g. `r.table.run()`) and insert them all into the second table, then re-create all the indexes, you will have successfully re-created the table.

Comment: Yes, clearly, step one is copy the documents, then step two is create the indexes, but as I said, there is no way to find out the names of the fields that create the indexes, only the names of the indexes, so how do I do that? Knowing the name of an index is "patient_id_type" doesn't tell me anything, the field could literally be "patient_id_type" or it could be two fields, "patient_id" and "type", or it could be three fields, "patient", "id", "type"... I need to know the fields, not the name of the index.